# Prove that $f$ has the maximum value on $[-a, a]$.

Tags: calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $a > 0$.
Let $f(x) := 2 x \sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \in [-a, 0) \cup (0, a]$ and $f(0) := 0$.

Prove that $f$ has the maximum value on $[-a, a]$.

My attempt is the following:

Let $b \in (0, a)$.
Then, $f$ has the maximum value $\max f_{[b, a]}$on $[b, a]$.
Let $-c \in (-a, 0)$.
Then, $f$ has the maximum value $\max f_{[-a, -c]}$ on $[-a, -c]$.

If we can choose $b$ and $-c$ such that if $x \in (-c, b)$, then $f(x) \leq \max\{\max f_{[b, a]}, \max f_{[-a, -c]}\}$, then the proof is done.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at $x=0?$

Comment: No. $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: What you wrote is not proof, but only conjecture. If it is true, then of course maximum will be found. At first glance it's obvious, that as your function is even, then it's enough to investigate $x>0$ case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea for you. In a very small neighborhood of $\;x=0\;$ the function is bounded, since

$\;2x\sin\frac1x\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0\;$ and $\;\left|\cos\frac1x\right|\le1\;$ , so say $\;|f(x)|\le M_1\;$ and $\;f(x_1)=M_1\;$ for $\;x,\,x_1\in(0,\,\epsilon)\;$ ,  with $\;\epsilon>0\;$ .

Now, at $\;[\epsilon,\,a]\;$, the function $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous and thus, by Weierstrass theorems, it both

is bounded there and attains in that interval its maximum/minimum value, say

$$\;f(x_2)=M_2\ge f(x)\,,\,\,\forall\,x\in[\epsilon,\,a],\,x_2\in[\epsilon,a]\;$$

Finally, just put the above together...and get your proof.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a rough proof.

Fix $a$.

As stated in the comments, we need only consider the interval $[0,a]$.

Let $\alpha = \min \{ \frac{a}{2}, \frac{1}{4\pi} \}.$
We break up the interval into two sets $A=[0,\alpha]$ and $B=[\alpha,a]$.  The set $B$ is compact, and $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $B$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ attains a maximum on $B$, call it $f^\star$.  $\forall x  \in A, f^\star \ge f(x),$ so $f^\star$ is the maximum on $[0,a]$ and thus on $[-a,a]$.